# Referencing function parameters with/without parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I am unfamiliar with referencing parameters with `()`.

Can someone explain the difference between the two following codes. Both return the correct value of 4.

In example 1: how are the values of functions `two` and `one` returned if two() and one() are not invoked?

**Example 1:**

```js
    
    function two() {
        return 2;
    }

    function one() {
        return 1;
    }

    function calculate(initialValue, incrementValue) {
        return initialValue() + incrementValue() + incrementValue();
    }

    console.log(calculate(two, one));
```

**Example 2:**

```js
  function two() {
      return 2;
  }

  function one() {
      return 1;
  }

  function calculate(initialValue, incrementValue) {
      return initialValue + incrementValue + incrementValue;
  }

  console.log(calculate(two(), one()));
```

Comment: Place `console.log` statements inside `one` and `two` and you'll understand the difference. Maybe another one in `calculate` helps even more: log the values of the parameters

Comment: `functionName` by itself is a reference to the function as a value, the uncalled function itself. `functionName()` is a **call** to the function, and in an expression the value is whatever calling the function returns.

Comment: @Pointy i'm more confused about the parenthesis next to the parameters initialValue, incrementValue as they are not functions.

Comment: @AdamDurrant as in normal algebra, `fn(x)` means "the result of calling a function called 'fn' and passing the value of 'x' as a parameter".

Comment: Sometimes in algebra function calls are written without parentheses, like in trigonometry: `sin x` means `sin(x)` but the parentheses are left off. Humans interpret algebra, but in computing languages must avoid ambiguity.

Comment: eg 1 passes in literal functions that you end up calling, eg 2 passes in numbers returned from calling the functions beforehand.. the difference is *where* the function gets called.

Comment: `calculate(initialValue, incrementValue)` indicates there are 2 params (positional). It does not specify if those params are values, functions, objects, or any other/s. In first case, those are functions (`two`, `one`). In second case, those are values (`2`, `1`), which are returned by function-calls (`two()`, `one()`).

Comment: @jsN00b thank you, that is clear. However, In example 1: how are the values of 'two' and 'one' returned if the functions two() and one() are not invoked?

Comment: @AdamDurrant in the snippet `let g = f; g();`, would you say that `f` is invoked? `g` is simply an alias of `f`. Example 1 is the same, `initialValue` and `incrementValue` are aliases of `two` and `one` respectively within the function call `calculate(two, one)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you're totally right, it's clear in my noggin now, thank you very very much that's super clear, I completely see that now. ❤️